# Lottery odds - Drömvinsten (Swedish Lotto)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, lotteries

Swedish Lotto rules can be found [here](https://cdn1.svenskaspel.net/content/cms/documents/779afe3f-0363-4c36-b79c-1881549a8cbc/1.13/spelregler-lotto-och-joker.pdf). As far as I know these are the most recent rules. In several places the probability of winning Drömvinsten is quoted as 1:337,915,578.
However, if I try to recalculate this number, I get 336,227,681 = 6724520 * 50.00025. I seem to match the odds for Joker and for the Swedish Lotto. But my 'product' is obviously off by some 1,7 million.

I understand for Joker the player needs to match either two leading or ending digits to be eligible for any payout.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Note: I don't speak Swedish, so I machine translated the rules.

**EDIT**: I meanwhile found a formula leading to the 1 in 337,915,578. See grey cells in my table. However I yet need to find out why the 17991 combinations are not 18000 (i.e. 9 combinations are seemingly not eligible to win that class).

My calculations are
[image: here]

Comment: I am not understanding what you are trying to calculate here, or what exactly your charts are for, but two things stand out to me as potentially alarming.  First, you write something along the lines of `probability = 1/odds`.  That is incorrect.  If you have odds in the format `for:against` such as the odds of drawing a queen out of a standard deck of cards with two jokers, the odds would be presented as `4:50` or `1:12.5` and would correspond to a probability of $\dfrac{4}{4+50}$ or $\dfrac{1}{\color{red}{1+}12.5}$ not $\frac{1}{12.5}$, that is `for / (for + against)`

Comment: Second, you have in this green part of the table some probabilities who you say sum up to $1$... but those numbers do not add up to $1$.  This should be clear at a glance.  Something is wrong there.

Comment: So if I exclude certain number combinations for the rows with k=3 and k = 2 I can actually match the official probability. However I yet need to find out why this is the case. See my math in the grey table [link](https://imgur.com/a/LaDpg1K) .  Can you let me know which part of the green table does not add up to 1 ? I use the convention odds = 1/p here.

Comment: Looking at the above, you talk about $\binom{35}{7}$ so... maybe this is some sort of lottery where you are drawing seven balls out of 35 possible?  But then later you have calculations involving numbers like $.0000001$ and $.0000009$ and such implying maybe you were picking a 7-digit string at random (*digits taken from $0,1,2,\dots,9$*)?  These seem contradictory to one another.  If you are talking about 7-digit strings at random, the chance a randomly selected string matches $k$ leading or ending digits your numbers are all off.

Comment: "*which part of the green table does not add up to 1*"  $.0000001 + .0000008+.000080+.000800+\dots$ looking at the final digit you have a single $1$ (*an odd number*) plus $8$ and several $0$'s (*even numbers*) which you should know `odd + even = odd`, similarly `odd + even + even + even + ... + even = odd`

Comment: Regarding odds. It is unclear why you bring in cards/poker and the likes. If you look at the Wikipedia page for [Powerball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerball#Prizes_and_odds) you will find a table with a column 'Odds of winning' showing the inverse of the winning probability for each class. This is the convention I am using above.

Comment: Context of what game is irrelevant.  If you are using odds = 1 / probability then you are using the word wrong.  The definition of odds should be standard across all mathematics.  If you want to talk about 1/probability then you should be using the word "*inverse probability*" which is a decidedly different concept than odds.

Comment: here is the [table](https://imgur.com/a/CD2xwGj) with more digits. Things do sum up to 1. The orignal table was simply rounded.

Comment: So, again, all of these numbers in your table are meaningless until described.  You have not yet provided definitions for how this lottery is conducted or what these numbers in your tables are meant to represent or how they were arrived at.  Are we using 35 balls labeled 1-35?  If not, why mention $\binom{35}{7}=6724520$?  Are we using seven separate sets of 10 balls labeled 0-9?  Are we sorting the balls in increasing order after being pulled?  Are players actively choosing their own lottery numbers or are they randomly assigned?  This is all still terribly unclear

Comment: The very first link in my post links to a PDF with the lottery rules. It is quite simple to translate this to English. You will find: Drömvinsten is a combination of the ordinary 7 out of 35 lottery (chance to win is some 1 in 6.724 million) and the Joker lottery where you have to match leading or ending digits of a random 7 digit number. I will rephrase my question: based on the PDF it is not apparent to me why the beige (or orange) numbers in the grey table (which leads to a winning probability consistent with the official PDF) are not equal to 18000 and 180000

Comment: For a random 7-digit string (*emphasis on the word "string" rather than "number" since we allow leading zeroes*), the probability another randomly selected 7-digit string matches exactly 0 leading or ending digits will be $\frac{9}{10}\times\frac{9}{10}=0.81\neq 0.800000010$.  For exactly two leading or ending to match note that if we were counting the leading two digits as matching we need the ending three digits to not match somehow, so it is not as simple as just saying $0.1\times 0.1\times 0.9\times 2$

Comment: Your attempted calculations seem to ignore the possibility of the ending digits outperforming the leading digits as well as your attempted calculations seem to ignore the possibility of the ending digits performing just as well as the leading digits.  For exactly two leading or ending to match, we need one of the following scenarios for (start,end):  $(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(0,2),(1,2)$ which would give $0.9^2(2\cdot .1^2 + 2\cdot .1^3 + .1^4)=0.017901$

Comment: The reason why the other numbers in your grey table match is because in order for $4$ or more numbers to match in the leading numbers it is impossible for the opposite direction to match or exceed the performance without causing all numbers to match.  Again, what any of this has to do with $\binom{35}{7}$ is beyond me.  It sounds like information to a completely separate and unrelated problem, that the swedish gaming controlling entity hosts multiple games with rules and odds that have nothing to do with one another beyond them being games of chance hosted by the same people.

Comment: Thanks. Your last two comments solve my question. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: look at the end of section 3.3. in this [pdf](https://cdn1.svenskaspel.net/content/cms/documents/779afe3f-0363-4c36-b79c-1881549a8cbc/1.13/spelregler-lotto-och-joker.pdf) it will show the probability 1:337,915,578 which is calculated as 6724520 * 50.25123. Which is "7 out of 35"  multiplied with the probability to match at least two digits in Joker

Comment: @amWhy The first six comments here were still in trying to understand the problem and are still useful to anyone else also unable to interpret the question.  The seventh and on were attempts to answer an attempted rewording of a potential misinterpretation of the problem which was not clear whether or not was actually going to wind up being relevant in the end until further clarification was given (*It still is unclear why $\binom{35}{7}$ should ever need to be mentioned*).  Asking for clarification is precisely what the comments section is for, not answer fields.

Comment: @JMoravitz  I understand.  I appreciate your patience.  I've upvoted your answer.  Apologies for not seeing this earlier.  Mainly, I get frustrated with those who use comments to answer.  In any case, thanks for bearing with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted calculations seem to ignore the possibility of the ending digits outperforming the leading digits as well as your attempted calculations seem to ignore the possibility of the ending digits performing just as well as the leading digits. For exactly two leading or ending to match, we need one of the following scenarios for (start,end): (2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(0,2),(1,2) which would give $0.9^2(2\cdot.1^2+2\cdot .1^3+.1^4)=0.017901$

Similarly for three leading or ending to match we have $0.9^2(2\cdot .1^3+2\cdot .1^4+2\cdot .1^5 + .1^6) = 0.00179901$ or zero leading or ending to match would just be $0.9^2 = 0.81$

The reason why the other numbers in your grey table match is because in order for 4 or more numbers to match in the leading numbers it is impossible for the opposite direction to match or exceed the performance without causing all numbers to match.

Answer (score 0):

**JMoravitz** answerd my question in his two comments above:

Your attempted calculations seem to ignore the possibility of the ending digits outperforming the leading digits as well as your attempted calculations seem to ignore the possibility of the ending digits performing just as well as the leading digits. For exactly two leading or ending to match, we need one of the following scenarios for (start,end): (2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(0,2),(1,2) which would give $0.9^2(2\cdot.1^2+2\cdot .1^3+.1^4)=0.017901$

The reason why the other numbers in your grey table match is because in order for 4 or more numbers to match in the leading numbers it is impossible for the opposite direction to match or exceed the performance without causing all numbers to match.